# Overriding Id in JSON object from a mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, hash, hashmap

I am struggling to override the attribute name in one of my models.

I would like to return an object to the front end (via JSON) with a field called id.

Now the problem comes that there is a field called _id (generated by mongo), that I cannot seem to get rid of.

I can override the id fine but is still returned as _id.

```
[Object]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "007"
_id: 123
```

I would like it to be
    [Object]
    0: Object
    $$hashKey: "007"
    id: 123

I have tried many hash manipulations, reject, except, and looping over and constructing, but cannot simply rename the field, or remove it for that matter.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot. The _id field is mandatory in all MongoDB documents (user generated documents, anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way was to override the as_json method and remove the hash there.

```
def as_json(*args)
   super.tap { |hash| hash["id"] = hash.delete "_id" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The "_id" field is mandatory in MongoDB documents.  [The manual says](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/):

> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add 
>   the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before 
>   inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, 
>   but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or 
>   application does not.

So you won't be able to work your way around this one.